# Riak inserting a list and querying a list

Tags: riak, riak-search

I was wondering if there was a effecient way of handling arrays/lists in Riak. Right now I'm storing the whole array as a string and searching the string to find out if a element exists in the array.

ID (key) : int[] (Value)

And also How do I write a map/reduce query to give all the keys for which the value array contains a element

For example 1 : 2,3,4
            2 : 2,5

How would I write a M/R query to give me all the keys for which value contains 2 the result is 1,2 in this case.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for a specific element in the list and are using the LevelDB backend, you could create a [secondary index](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/developing/usage/secondary-indexes/) that will contain the values of the array. Secondary indexes in Riak may contain multiple values and can be searched for equality, which should allow you to search for single elements in the array without having to resort to MapReduce.

If you need to make more complicated queries based on either several elements in the list or other parameters, you could retrieve a subset of records based on the secondary index and then process them further on the client side or perhaps even through a MapReduce job.